# How to properly remove a table from folder migration in laravel? (With artisan command)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

when you use comand by example:

```
php artisan make:migration create_tasks_table --create=tasks
```

it creates a table file and dependency link inside of file

> \vendor\composer\autoload_classmap.php

How I can do something like?

```
php artisan remove:table:file create_Task_table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such command exists in `artisan` console. However, you can either make one such command or just delete the migration and execute the following command in the console.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Comment: it just re-compiles the file of all the classes that need to be auto-loaded